# Cant copy files from one document library to another- sensenet

Tags: sensenet

I am using sensenet and react based client for front end. while copying a file from one document library to another I am getting the following error:

> "Cannot copy a list item into an another list".

Can anybody tell me how i can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is currently by design. The reason is that content lists (doc lib, task list, etc.) *may* contain local list fields. If you had a document in a list with a custom metadata field filled with a value, you would *loose that value* if you copied the document to another list.

#### Workaround 1

If you do not need the list/library functionality (custom metadata fields, etc.) than store documents in a simple *folder* instead of a list. This will let you copy those documents wherever you want - even *into* a list. In this case you have to take care of setting the allowed child types (most likely File) somewhere on the parent chain (e.g. on the workspace), because you cannot set this value on simple folders.

#### Workaround 2

Copy files using a temp folder. It is allowed to copy a file from a list to a temp folder, and also copy a file from a folder *into* a list. I know, this is not very convenient and we are considering changing this behavior to make it more permissive, but this is how currently works.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, will try second model